# VMWare CentOS 6 Guest OS IP address is on a different network

Tags: centos, vmware, ip-address

Good day.

I am not sure if "network" is the right terminology but my Windows PC and VMWare Guest OS has a different network address.

```
Windows PC: 192.168.3.x
CentOS 6 Guest: 192.168.239.x
```

On my other Guest OS (Ubuntu) it uses the network `192.168.3.x`. I am not sure why on my CentOS 6 it is different.

I tried to change the CentOS IP Address to static with `192.168.239.x` and it connects. `192.168.3.x` doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Found my own answer. On VMWare Network Adapter Setting, change the Network Connection from NAT to Bridged